# Android refreshing ListView in fragment every 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have problem but i didn't find any solution here so i'm writing. I'm trying to create an app which download and parse data from polish stock. I want to update values of companies every 30 seconds, I do it but i can't refresh current tab, if i want to see new values i how to switch tab two time and then back, and then i can see new values. I want to update datas without switching tabs.

MainActivity

```
    pobieranie_wartosci.start();
//this starts Thread for updating data  


    // init tabhost
    this.initializeTabHost(savedInstanceState);

    // init ViewPager
    this.initializeViewPager();

}


private void initializeViewPager() {
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    fragments.add(new Tab1Fragment());
    fragments.add(new Tab2Fragment());
    fragments.add(new Tab1Fragment());
    fragments.add(new Tab1Fragment());
    fragments.add(new Tab3Fragment());
    fragments.add(new Tab1Fragment());


    this.myViewPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    this.viewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    this.viewPager.setAdapter(this.myViewPagerAdapter);
    this.viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    onRestart();

}
```

im also puting here my Thread which update data

```
Thread pobieranie_wartosci = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {

            int r = zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.size()-1;
            for(int i =0; i<=r;i++){
                try 
                {
                    zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(i).transformacja_ceny(new Cena().execute(zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(i).numer).get());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(0).cena_kupna++;

                System.out.println("cena :" + zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(0).cena_kupna);
            }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        }
    }

};
```

And last thing which may be useful is MyPageAdapter

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return fragments.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at using Loaders ? They can load data into fragments asynchronously which sounds along the lines of what you want to achieve (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

Comment: i read about .notifyDataSetChanged(); can someone write here how and where in my code may i use it?